# Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'include_relative'

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll, I am trying to use the "include_relative" tag in the layout.html file.

**layout.html**

```
<div class="panel">  
<div class="content-container panel-wrapper">

{% include_relative /hello.md %}

</div><!--end content container-->
</div><!--end panel-->

<div class="panel">  
<div class="content-container panel-wrapper">

{% include_relative /bye.md %}
```

When I run the program it says:

**Error:**

```
Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'include_relative' in layout
```

I know this tag exists as it is described on the Jekyll documentation web page. I have also used other tags in the layout.html file that work properly, so its specifically the "include_relative" tag that I am struggling with.
How can I get this tag to properly be recognized?

Comment: and when you do a `jekyll -v` what's the result ?

Comment: According to the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#including-files-relative-to-another-file) on `include_relative` the file passed must exist relative to the file containing the tag. My interpretation of that makes me wonder if you can't have a leading /. Try putting hello.md and bye.md in your _layouts directory and see if the error goes away. I vaguely recall a Jekyll issue where tag errors misleadingly reported an "Unknown tag" error so also do what @DavidJacquel suggested.

Comment: I updated my version to 2.5.3, and the tag worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: Please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as correct if it worked!